# Webdav mounting on XP

Tags: windows, ssl, windows-xp, webdav

I have an SSL tunnel application which transmits data from port 80 to 443 (sets up port 80 as local server and reads/write received data to HTTPS). I can mount this application in Windows 7 or Virtual-PC XP (using `net use X: http://localhost/drive/` command.

The problem is, when I'm trying to mount this drive in real XP >= SP2 (tested only on domain PC's), I receive 2 errors repeating, but I'm still able to open this location in browser.

> System error 59 has occurred. An unexpected network error occurred
>
> System error 67 has occurred. The network name cannot be found

There is no network traffic at server side (no request from client recorded in the logs), SSL tunnel is established properly.

I was starting to apply MS fixes and remarks like: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/875441, but nothing happens.

There are no malformation in hosts.etc.

Using alias for localhost is also not working, and its only the case in Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-webdav-network-drive.html) Windows XP can only connect to port 80, not 443.  It also suggests that for better support of Web Dav folders to install [MS KB 907306](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907306).